# How to parse object array that has been stringified using backslashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been searching for the correct regex for converting this string to JSON. It works if there is a single object in the array, but I believe the comma is messing it up somehow.

```js
const json = "{\"userId\":44, \"userName\": \"Jim Coleman\"},{\"userId\":33515, \"userName\": \"Grace Mamaradlo\"}";
const obj = JSON.parse(json.replace(/("[^"]*"\s*:\s*)(\d{17,})/g, '$1"$2"'));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: If javascript doesn't have a built-in JSON parser, the world has ended. Why do you even try to parse JSON in its native habitat?

Comment: The backslashes aren't part of the (JSON) string. They are part of the string literal in. The problem with that JSON is that it contains multiple elements like in an array, but it isn't surrounded by square brackets. You really shouldn't ever use regex on JSON.

Comment: @texas697 Surround the string  with square brackets before you parse it. Or even better, make sure that where that string is coming from, is providing you with valid JSON that can be parsed.

Comment: @texas697 The solution to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong except that the list of objects was not contained within square brackets

```js
const json = "{\"userId\":44, \"userName\": \"Jim Coleman\"},{\"userId\":33515, \"userName\": \"Grace Mamaradlo\"}";

console.log(JSON.parse(`[${json}]`))
```